# Scoring in GridSearchCV for XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, parameters, xgboost, grid-search

I'm currently trying to analyze data for the first time using XGBoost. I want to find the best parameters using GridsearchCV. I want to minimize the root mean squared error and to do this, I used "rmse" as eval_metric. However, scoring in grid search does not have such a metric. I found on this site that the "neg_mean_squared_error" does the same, but I found that this gives me different results than the RMSE. When I calculate the root of the absolute value of the "neg_mean_squared_error", I get a value of around 8.9 while a different function gives me a RMSE of about 4.4. 
I don't know what goes wrong or how I get these two functions to agree/give the same values?

Because of this problem, I get wrong values as "best_params_" which give me a higher RMSE than some values I initially started with to tune.

Can anyone please explain me how to get score on the RMSE in the grid search or why my code gives different values?

Thanks in advance.

```
def modelfit(alg, trainx, trainy, useTrainCV=True, cv_folds=10, early_stopping_rounds=50):
    if useTrainCV:
        xgb_param = alg.get_xgb_params()
        xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(trainx, label=trainy)
        cvresult = xgb.cv(xgb_param, xgtrain, num_boost_round=alg.get_params()['n_estimators'], nfold=cv_folds,
                          metrics='rmse', early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
        alg.set_params(n_estimators=cvresult.shape[0])

    # Fit the algorithm on the data
    alg.fit(trainx, trainy, eval_metric='rmse')

    # Predict training set:
    dtrain_predictions = alg.predict(trainx)
    # dtrain_predprob = alg.predict_proba(trainy)[:, 1]
    print(dtrain_predictions)
    print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainy, dtrain_predictions)))

    # Print model report:
    print("\nModel Report")
    print("RMSE : %.4g" % np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(trainy, dtrain_predictions)))

 param_test2 = {
 'max_depth':[6,7,8],
 'min_child_weight':[2,3,4]
}

grid2 = GridSearchCV(estimator = xgb.XGBRegressor( learning_rate =0.1, n_estimators=2000, max_depth=5,
 min_child_weight=2, gamma=0, subsample=0.8, colsample_bytree=0.8,
 objective= 'reg:linear', nthread=4, scale_pos_weight=1, random_state=4),
 param_grid = param_test2, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=4,iid=False, cv=10, verbose=20)
grid2.fit(X_train,y_train)
# Mean cross-validated score of the best_estimator
print(grid2.best_params_, np.sqrt(np.abs(grid2.best_score_))), print(np.sqrt(np.abs(grid2.score(X_train, y_train))))
modelfit(grid2.best_estimator_, X_train, y_train)
print(np.sqrt(np.abs(grid2.score(X_train, y_train))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `GridSearchCV` the scoring parameter is transformed so that higher values are always better than lower values.  In your example `neg_mean_squared_error` is just a negated version of RMSE.  You should not interpret `neg_mean_squared_error` to be RMSE, rather in your cross-validation you should compare values of `neg_mean_squared_error` where a higher value is better than lower values.

In the scoring parameter portion of the `model_evaluation` documentation this behavior is mentioned.

[Scikit-Learn Scoring Parameter Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I get this, but how come the values of the 'print(np.sqrt(np.abs(grid2.score(X_train, y_train))))' statement differs from the modelfit 'print("RMSE : %.4g" % np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(trainy, dtrain_predictions)))'?

Comment: Also, is it wrong to minimize the mean squared error when I actually want to minimize the RMSE? I think this boils down to the same thing, because if you minimize something, the root is also minimized. Is this correct?

Comment: `grid2.best_score_` is the best performance the model achieved on the holdout data during cross validation.  You're then taking that estimator and fitting it to the entire training set and using those predictions to calculate the RMSE.  So the difference boils down to the scores are not based on the same data in their calculations.

Comment: Thanks, but does this explain the difference in RMSE between "modelfit(grid2.best_estimator_, X_train, y_train)" (where I fit on the grid2.best_estimator_ and then calculate the RMSE) and "np.sqrt(np.abs(grid2.score(X_train, y_train)))" in the last line?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? We're finding the exact same thing and don't see how the best_score is consistent with the metric we think we're using for the scoring when calculated by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It's because XGBoostRegressor.score returns [the coefficient of determination of the prediction](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.score), not RMSE.